# converting 'int' to 'long' or accessing too long array with 'long'

Tags: java, arrays, int, long-integer

Let's say I have an array that is long enough to access any of its index with `int`, is there any way to access the index of such an array with `long`? And how the Java handle this kind of array? Example:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,5,2,4........9,2,1}
```

Assume in the above array that `9,2,1` are at indices that are beyond the range of `int` (2<sup>31</sup>).
How would I access these elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't - array indexes are always `int` values in Java. It doesn't allow for an array with more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements.

The length of an array is represented by the `length` field, which is of type `int`. Therefore it is impossible to create an array with a length greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html) doesn't explicitly call this out, but you can infer it from the types involved.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html which I was looking for too :P

Comment: The spec does mention it when talking about array creation expressions: "the type of a dimension expression must not be long."

Comment: @Jon Skeet, it is specified in the spec. But it isn't really explicit.

Comment: Are List/Set also limited? What happens if you do toArray on a List/Set that is larger than MAX_VALUE?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: Well `List.get()` takes an `int` index... I don't think any of the collections are really expected to handle more than 2 billion elements.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, @willcodejavaforfood it depends on the implementation. You "could" have a list working with longs (and with a `get(long)`). But it would be playing with fire and breaking most of the Collection contract.

Comment: Interesting, never really thought about that :)

Comment: Do you really have an array with over 2 billion elements? This seems slightly excessive, even with the huge amounts of memory available on modern computers. I'm wondering if this is a real application or just a hypothetical question. Like, what, you have a table with an entry for every person in the world or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a that long array. But this idea has been proposed for the project coin.

> Arrays must be indexed by `int` values; `short`, `byte`, or `char` values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion [(§5.6.1)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#170952) and become `int` values. **An attempt to access an array component with a `long` index value results in a compile-time error**.

---

**Resources :**

- [JLS - Array Access](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#25566)
- [JLS - Array Creation Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#46168)
- [Project coin - Large array V1](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000851.html) - [V2](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000869.html)

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the length and index values must be ints.  If you really need this, there are workarounds though.  For instance, you could have an array of very big int arrays.  You could then do some modulo arithmetic on a long to determine which array you want and which index in that array is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a custom data structure, try this:

```
/**
* Because java uses signed primitives only the least significant 31 bits of an int are used to index arrays,
* therefore only the least significant 62 bits of a long are used to index a LongArray
* 
* @author aaron
*/
public class LongArray<Element> {

    //inclusive
    public static final long maximumSize = (~0)>>>2;//0x 00 FF FF FF  FF FF FF FF
    public static final long minimumSize = 0;

    //Generic arrays are forbidden! Yay dogma!
    private Object[][] backingArray;

    private static int[] split(long L) {
        int[] rtn = new int[2];
        rtn[1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE & (int)(L>>7);
        rtn[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE & (int)L;
        return rtn;
    }
    private static long join(int[] ia) {
        long rtn = 0;
        rtn |= ia[0];
        rtn <<= 7;
        rtn |= ia[1];
        return rtn;
    }

    private static boolean isValidSize(long L) {
        return L<=maximumSize && L>=minimumSize;
    }

    public LongArray(long size){
        if (!isValidSize(size)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size requested was invalid, too big or negative");

        //This initialises the arrays to be only the size we need them to be
        int[] sizes = split(size);
        backingArray = new Object[sizes[0]][];
        for (int index = 0; index<backingArray.length-1; index+=1) {
            backingArray[index] = new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
        }
        backingArray[backingArray.length-1] = new Object[sizes[1]];
    }

    public Element get(long index) {
        int[] ia = split(index);
        return (Element)backingArray[ia[0]][ia[1]];
    }
    public void set(long index, Element element) {
        int[] ia = split(index);
        backingArray[ia[0]][ia[1]] = element;
    }

}
```