# Java Implicit conversion char to int?

Tags: java, char, int, type-conversion

I was given an interview question to output the most frequent occurrence of a character.

Given this string "aaxxaabbaa". The character 'a' is the most frequent.

The following code was something that I found searching on the internet. Note: I implemented it with 2 loops which is in-efficient (different topic)

```
public static char findMostUsedChar(String str){
    char maxchar = ' ';
    int maxcnt = 0;
    // if you are confident that your input will be only ascii, then this array can be size 128.
    // Create a character counter
    **int[] charcnt = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];**
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
        char **ch** = str.charAt(i);
        // increment this character's cnt and compare it to our max.
        if (**charcnt[ch]**++ >= maxcnt) {
            maxcnt = charcnt[ch];
            maxchar = ch;
        }
    }
    return maxchar;
}
```

They declared an int array, found the character at a specific index (i.e. 'a') then used as an index.
After tracing the code out on the debugger in eclipse, I still don't understand how using a character to represent an int index works without explicitly casting it or using charVal.getNumericValue()?? Even most of the S.O. char to int topics explicitly cast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501867/how-to-set-array-dimension-to-long-number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Array access expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3) undergo implicit unary numeric promotion, which will widen an expression to `int`.

> The index expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1).

The `char` datatype is widened to `int` via its Unicode value, e.g. `'A'` -> `65`.