# Can't declare a long array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Code:

```
 long Height ;
 long[][] results = new long[Height][Height];
```

Eclipse giving me an  error 
But:

```
long[][] results = new long[(int) Height][(int) Height];
```

this is not. I want to have a range of long, So i want a long array

Comment: Generally, variables in Java should be lower-cased (for example, `height`).

Comment: Clarify what you mean by _I want to have a range of long_.

Comment: Multiple duplicates, also including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878309/java-array-with-more-than-4gb-elements .

Answer (score 8):

The array will contains `long` values, but the array size accepts only `int`s

Comment: I would add that even though `Height` is cast, the array still behaves like an array of longs.

Comment: i want to have that range of numbers

Comment: @user3856587 why would you want an array of *94109400* elements? That maybe won't fit in memory.

Comment: Maybe you want inside the array longs, and not the size?

Answer (score 2):

Array size should be state using an int. You can't use long for that.
So the maximum 2D array that you can have is

```
long[][] results = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1][Integer.MAX_VALUE -1];
```

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is **2147483647**

So if you want to have more than that then it is better look for some other data structure