# finding prime numbers less than a LONG number using sieve

Tags: java, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have to find number of prime numbers less than or equal to a given number `n`. I am using Sieve of Eratosthenes for finding primes.

This is the code I've written:

```
static int find_prime(int n) {
    boolean[] arr = new boolean[n+1];
    Arrays.fill(arr, true);

for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
    if(arr[i]==true) {
        for(int j=2*i; j<=n; j+=i)
            arr[j] = false;
    }
}
int count=0;
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
    //System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    if (arr[i] == true)
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This code works well for `integer` values, but I have to implement it for `long` numbers. And Java doesn't allow creating `long` size array so `boolean[] arr = new boolean[n+1];`
 doesn't work.
Can someone suggest me a way to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java array with more than 4gb elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878309/java-array-with-more-than-4gb-elements)

Comment: You've already purchased 10 [Exabytes](http://www.whatsabyte.com/) of memory for your sieve, right?

Comment: There are more space-efficient ways to store a sequence of booleans. A bit field, for example. Also, you don't really have to represent even numbers in the sieve.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you can suggest me a better way to find the answer.

Comment: @khelwood is there a better way for doing this other than sieve?

Comment: You can write a sieve without using a boolean array. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array

Comment: @khelwood This would take him to 2^36 - a great deal of an improvement on 2^31, but still quite a bit short of 2^63 that he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I make it 2^37 if you use an array of longs, but I see your point.

Comment: @khelwood I was off by 1, it's 2^37, not 2^36. 64 is 2^6, and the max array size is 2^31, so you can store up to 2^(6+31) bits. Skipping even numbers brings you up to 2^38.

Comment: You might be interested in a [segmented sieve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810).

Comment: simple [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bprimes%5d%20is%3aa) gives you [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625663/calculating-and-printing-the-nth-prime-number/9704912?s=1|8.7171#9704912).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't have enough memory to represent the entire sieve, because it is in exabytes. Even [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) is not going to fit all the indexes that you need, because ultimately it [uses](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/BitSet.java) an array of `long`s to store the bits.

You can find your answer with a mixed approach:

- Build and run a sieve up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
- Harvest primes up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` into an array of `long`s
- Observe that you can stop checking for divisors upon reaching square root of candidate number `c`
- This means that you already have all potential divisors for values above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
- Use array of divisors to filter numbers between `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `n`

Since you do not need to store additional primes after `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, your code would not run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that BitSet doesn't reduce the memory requirement enough. If I figured this right, it would still require as much as 2^60 bytes of memory. I don't believe current common desktop processors can address that much.